# Wallpaper change and power plan in win 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, power-options

My notebook (Windows 8.1) has been doing something strange with the desktop background slideshow.

I set it automatically wallpaper change every 5 minutes. It does work, usually. However, sometimes it seems to forget to change and stays at one wallpaper until I reset it. I doubt if this happens when the notebook is using battery, since I never turn off the power. Is there anybody who know why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a power plan setting to control whether the desktop slideshow is operative.

Open Power Options in Control Panel. Click *Change plan settings* next to your selected plan. Click *Change advanced power settings*.

[image: advanced power options]
<sup>Since I'm on a desktop, I only get a single setting for each option.</sup>

Expand *Desktop background settings*, then *Slide show*. If you want the slideshow to always go on, set both *On battery* and *Plugged in* to *Available*. Click OK, then *Save changes*.